British series, 2/3 parts, probably around 2004-7, people gradually being killed because of childhood incident
I would like the title of a British TV series, standalone, made in approx 2004 - 2007, set at the same time. No successive series. Wasn't set in London. 
People approx 35-40 years old, I think, were gradually being killed because of something that happened at school/in the playground when they were very small - 5-7 years old? They were all in the same class. This was the common factor in their murders, but I cannot remember the specific original incident or why the murderer was taking revenge. 
The lead actor, who I thought was Martin Kemp - but nothing about this on IMDb - investigates, as he assumes he is on the list of future victims. One of his school friends has had a complete breakdown largely as a result of the earlier incident, and is living rough/halfway houses. I thought this was Vincent Regan, but again, not. I have only mentioned the actors who I thought is was as it gives an idea of their type. Thanks.

When was the series made? When was it set?

This sounds a lot like Class of '76 from 2005, but Carlyle looks nothing like Kemp.

Thanks,Walt. That's it. After I had to edit my post, I did another long google search, and came across "Class of 76" in a vague connection to my umpteenth Martin Kemp search. I watched it on Youtube yesterday. The character that I thought was Vincent Regan looks enough like him to be Regan's brother/cousin at about the time he played in "Troy". No idea where I got Martin Kemp from, and why I didn't remember it as Robert Carlisle, as I am much more familiar with him than Kemp.Thanks again.

No problem! You can put up your comment as an answer, if you want.

"Monroe: Class of 76" with Robert Carlyle

Cars swerve to avoid an agitated man wandering on a freeway until the man is hit by a truck and killed. Eyewitnesses said the man, Pat Fisher, was clearly disturbed, and some on the police force think that no other explanation or investigation is necessary-- except for Detective Tom Monroe (Robert Carlyle, The Full Monty). Finding newspaper clippings, class photos and tape recordings about Fisher's classmates dating back to 1976 in the dead man's apartment, Monroe discovers three other mysterious deaths among the class. Soon the deaths and their strange circumstances, which date back to the kidnapping and murder of 10-year-old Amy Irvine, begin to haunt the detective as much as they did Fisher. In this tense, gripping psychological thriller, Monroe must unravel the mystery of the Class of '76 before, as Fisher warns from beyond the grave, "It won't be suicide, won't be an accident. Every one of us, murdered

